# Datagridview will not react to a cell click event unless header column is clicked, why?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

So I have a datagridview that auto generates columns based on the data I pull from a database. Now I also have a cell click event for the datagridview, however this event only fires if the column header is click. It will not fire if I click any of the cells populated inside the datagridview, why?

```
// This is in the designer code
this.dgvScheduled.CellClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dgvScheduled_CellClick);

// This is in my main forms application
private void dgvScheduled_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

{

    ChangeIsNoShow(e);

}
```

With the event subscribed in the designer code and the event in the application, it does not make sense why it does not execute when I click on cell that is not the header cell.

Comment: The code you provided does not reproduce the problem.  Are you using the debugger to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes, I set a breakpoint at the cell click event. It's hard to reproduce the problem without showing the datagridview, but essentially all the rows in the datagridview should respond with this event if clicked upon, but they don't. Only their column headers do.

Comment: Try duplicating this issue in a new project.

Comment: It should work. You do have data/rows, right?

Comment: @TaW `It will not fire if I click any of the cells populated inside the datagridview`

Comment: Correct, I do have rows of data. Which is why it is odd that it is not executing when I select a cell in one of the rows.

Comment: So you can select cells..? Sounds like a broken control.